# Weird behavior of fread | A function behaves differently when called from main and differently when called from some other function

Tags: c, pointers, program-entry-point, fread

I wrote a function to read given number of bytes from a specified place from a file. This works as expected when called from main. But when it is called from some other function which in turn is called from main, it reads certain extra garbage characters as well (Some of which are non-printable).

Please explain what is happening and how do I prevent it. The code and the corresponding output are given below:

EDIT: The final goal is to calculate a hash of this data, create a packet of (data + hash) and send it via a TCP socket to a another node in the network.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char * read_from_file(char * filename, int offset, int n_bytes)
{
    printf("Inside read function\n");
    printf("offset: %d\n",offset);
    printf("n_bytes: %d\n",n_bytes);
    char * bfr;
    FILE * f_ptr;
    int count;

    f_ptr = fopen (filename,"r");
    if(f_ptr==NULL)
    {
        printf("File not found\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    //Set the offset position
    fseek(f_ptr, offset , SEEK_SET);
    //memory aloocation
    bfr = malloc (sizeof(char)*n_bytes);
    if (bfr == NULL)
    {
        printf("Memory allocation problem\n");
        exit (2);
    }
    count = fread(bfr,1,n_bytes,f_ptr);
    printf("no. of characters read from file: %d\n",count);
    printf("string read: %s\n", bfr);
    printf("Length of string read: %zd\n",strlen(bfr));

    if (count != n_bytes)
    {
        printf("Error in reading the file");
        exit(1);
    }
    // Close the file
    fclose (f_ptr);
    printf("Exiting read function\n\n");
    return bfr;
}

int send_file()//nc_args_t * nc_args)
{
    printf("Inside send_file\n");
    char * data;
    data = malloc (10);
    data = read_from_file("alphabet.txt", 0, 10);
    printf("Length of data: %d\n",strlen(data));
    printf("Data Read: %s\n", data);

}

int main()
{
    char * data;
    data = read_from_file("alphabet.txt", 0, 10);
    printf("Length of data: %zd\n",strlen(data));
    printf("Data Read: %s\n", data);
    printf("\nCalling send_file\n");
    send_file();
}
```

OUTPUT

```
Inside read function
offset: 0
n_bytes: 10
no. of characters read from file: 10
string read: ABCDEFGHIJ
Length of string read: 10
Exiting read function

Length of data: 10
Data Read: ABCDEFGHIJ

Calling send_file
Inside send_file
Inside read function
offset: 0
n_bytes: 10
no. of characters read from file: 10
string read: ABCDEFGHIJLsE
Length of string read: 14
Exiting read function

Length of data: 14
Data Read: ABCDEFGHIJLsE
```

Answer (score 2):

After the call

```
count = fread(bfr,1,n_bytes,f_ptr);
```

`bfr` isn't necessarily a string because it may not be null-terminated, so you can't print its content using `printf("string read: %s\n", bfr);` or get its length using `strlen`. You need to print every character in a loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n_bytes; i++)
    printf("%c", bfr[i]);
printf("\n");
```

EDIT

Thanks for @Jonathan Leffer's comment, this looks way much better:

```
printf("%.*s\n", count, bfr);
```

Comment: If `bfr` is not `\0` terminated, might not the other bytes be non-printable such that a format other than `%c` is warranted?  Or if only text skip the loop and use `printf("%.*s\n", n_bytes, bfr);`?

Comment: @chux You are right, printing hex would be better, assuming that the data are arbitrary binary data. It depends on what the OP wants, according to the example, the data are printable characters.

Comment: You could use `printf("%.*s\n", count, bfr);` assuming that the data read doesn't contain any zero (null) bytes.

Answer (score 1):

You're not allocating an additional byte for the string's null terminator, and you're not guaranteeing that terminator is present.  You must allocate `n_bytes + 1` for the buffer and make sure the final byte is zero.

Comment: Actually, I want to calculate the hash of this, create a packet and send it over via a TCP socket to some other network. Will I still be needing '\0' for that?

Comment: I don't know if what you want to send requires a null-terminated string or an array of chars with a given length.  Consult the specification for the TCP packet you want to send.